# StackOverflowException using Saxon via C# in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, saxon, stack-overflow

My code tries to compile a big XSLT2 transform (not complex, just lots of simple - about 24,000 lines from MapForce) in C# (.NET 4.5 on 64-bit Win7) in Saxon HE (9.5 latest).

When I run this from a console application, it works fine (albeit slow).  Executing the transform takes 200-300ms and I get the output I'm expecting.

When I run the same code wrapped in a WCF service in IIS (7.5), or as a http handler in IIS, I get a StackOverflowException shortly after executing the compile command (the next line is never executed).

If I try with a small transform, my code works in IIS.

The event and IIS logs don't show anything that appears useful.

Other than building Saxon from source (apparently a bit hard - any pointers welcome) to see if that helps, does anyone have any ideas where to start with this one?

Comment: Another observation: I suspect the overflow is because of a deep expression tree. Look in your stylesheet for long templates or functions. When code is generated automatically, (e.g. by Mapforce) it can sometimes be very verbose.

Comment: Michael - thanks, you're right.  The IIS worker process has a reduced stack size, and it couldn't cope with the needs of the transform, whereas our non-IIS test harness (with the default, larger stack) could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fiddling, it turns out that the IIS worker process has, by default, a much smaller stack than a standalone application does, and this was the cause of the problem.  You can modify the .exe to change this, but it was simpler for us to create a new thread and specify the thread's stack size on creation.  Problem solved instantly.  One to remember!